# Combination of various powers of $\sin\theta$.

Tags: trigonometry, cubics

I'm confusing about a question:

> For three positive constants $A$, $B$, $C$, find $\theta$ (express in $A$, $B$ and $C$).
>
> $$A\sin^6\theta - A\sin^4\theta + B\sin^2\theta -C = 0$$

So, when I do it the trigonometric way,

$A\sin^4\theta(\sin^2\theta-1) + B\sin^2\theta - C = 0$

$-A\sin^4\theta\cos^2\theta + B\sin^2\theta -C = 0$

$-\frac{A}{4}\sin^2\theta\sin^22\theta +B\sin^2\theta -C = 0$

I found myself unable to continue.

Anyone get some ideas? Appreciate your help.

Comment: if we take $x=sin^2\theta$ then the equation reduces to a cubic equation whic has root in terms of $A,B,C$ hence we're done. but i don't know the exact formula for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking $x=\sin \theta\implies$ $$Ax^3-Ax^2+Bx-C=0\\\implies x^3-x^2+Dx-E=0,\ D:=\frac{B}{A},\ E:\frac{C}{A}$$ Now use [Cardano's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function) to solve this cubic equation to solve for $x$ and hence finally get $\theta$.